# Find the vertical distance between the top most '1' and the bottom most '1' in a matrix in R

Tags: r, csv

I have successfully imported a csv file into R. It is a 6 by 6 matrix.

```
0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 0
0 1 1 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 1
0 1 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
```

'1' exists in the second row and also exists in the second last row. So the distance between them vertically is 4.

Would I use the dist function to calculate this? And if so how would I implement it to give me the value of 4?

Comment: isn't the vertical distance 3?

Comment: In your example the 2nd row and the 5th row 1s are both in column 2. Do you want to look column by column, or does column not matter?

Comment: No the column doesn't matter, just the vertical distance between the top most and bottom most '1'.

Comment: Yeah you would be correct. I was including the '1' that I started from oops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
diff(range(which(rowSums(mat) > 0)))
# [1] 3
```

Explanation: since the data is binary, we can look at the distance between rows where the row sum is >0.

Adapting Sathish's nicely share data, this works:

```
mat <- matrix(as.integer(unlist(strsplit('0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0', " "))),
              nrow = 6, ncol = 6, byrow = TRUE)
```